# Why are missing textures replaced by a black and purple checkerboard?

Tags: graphics, 3d, textures

In many different games, such as Minecraft and TF2, the default texture is a black and purple checkerboard. Even games that don't use that exact texture incorporate elements of it. Borderlands 2 uses a white and purple checkerboard, and Skyrim uses a solid purple texture. Why is the black and purple checkerboard so prevalent as a default texture?

Comment: Some games also use overly saturated red.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely to represent a standard, noticeable and well-thought missing texture placement, so that the players across games simply think "Well yep, that's a missing texture,  it's purple/black/checkerboards/white&black." As not to confuse them. ***tl;dr: It's consistent and players will recognize it.***

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume it's because the RGB color for purple is (1,0,1), an easy to type color especially when you're frustrated. Most often a developer generates a full black texture (0,0,0), then setting every other pixel to (1,0,1) with a double loop